# Removing an associated object with a link_to to the update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true
end
```

CategoriesController:

```
private  
  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:title, questions_attributes: [:id, :category_id, :title, :_destroy])
  end
```

---

In the view I have a category displaying all it's posts (`CategoriesController#show`).

Each post is deletable.

How could I construct a `link_to` helper that deletes a post by updating the category?

Answer (score 0):

```
link_to "Remove question", category_path(category, question_attributes(id: question.id, _destroy: true)), method: :put
```

Comment: little tip: use 4 spaces before your code to style it OR select it and use Ctrl+k while editing your answer

Comment: Rails doesn't seem to like `question_attributes` in the url arguments: "undefined method `question_attributes'".

Answer (score 0):

```
= link_to 'Delete question', question, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}
```

and in routes.rb

```
resources :questions
```

and in your controller do what's necessary

```
class QuestionController < ApplicationController
   def delete
      question = Question.find(params[:id])
      question.category = nil #or whatever you need to do
      question.save
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
link_to "Remove question", category_path(category: { questions_attributes: {id: question.id, _destroy: true}}), method: :put
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be best done using the [`.delete` collection method](http://neyric.com/2007/07/08/how-to-delete-a-many-to-many-association-with-rails/) in your controller:

```
#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
def delete_question
   @category = Category.find params[:category_id]
   question = category.questions.find params[:id]

   @category.questions.delete question
end
```

To get this working, you'll need to use the `routes` and `link_to` helper like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :categories do
   patch "question/:id", to: "categories#delete_question" #-> domain.com/categories/15/question/1
end

#app/views/categories/show.html.erb
<% @category.questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= link_to "Remove Question", category_question_removal_path(category, question) method: :patch %>
<% end %>
```